# Rails: How to set up Active Record Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am relatively new to rails and doing the simplest thing: Associate users and posts. I read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), but what more than this do I need to do to make it work (or is this the only thing)?:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Update:**
I can't make it work. When I make a post with a signed in user, I get false when I do `@user.posts.any?` in the console. My code:

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :default_values
```

user.rb (I use devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

20130320162700_create_posts.rb

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. As long as the `users` table has a `post_id` column. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: this should work, you should be able to call `@user.posts` to get all the posts for a given user or @post.user to get the user for a given post. Are u getting any errors ?!

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but I get `[]` if I do @user.posts, even if I have made some posts. But are `users` table going to have a `post_id`? Isnt it just `posts` table that is going to have a `user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to include User's id in the migration that creates the posts table. 
In your migration file (in the db/migrate folder you will find a file named like 20130325105934_create_posts.rb)

Inside the file you will find the migration code. Along the other declared attributes add

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
     ...... 
     t.integer :user_id
     ......
  end
```

end

It should be enough to make things roll :-)

Inside your code then you can create a new user as

```
@user = User.new(:login => "my_user", .....)
```

and then add posts with one of these two ways (there are others two).

```
post = Post.new(:title => "something", :text => "more of something", :user_id = @user.id)
```

or

```
   post = Post.new(:title => "something", :text => "more of something")
   @user.posts << post
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast reply. I have now set it all up, but if i do a `@user.posts.any?` I get false, even if @user is a user I have made some posts with. Any idea why?

Comment: Weird, i made a toy project, run the console and works for me. which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I added some code that you can use as a guide. leave a message if it doesn't work

Comment: I am using `Rails 3.2.13`. I tried the last bit of code (`post = Post.new():title....` `@user.posts << post`) in the console, and it worked! But I dont know how to test it inside my code? I did the `add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer`, did the migration and added `t.integer :user_id` to the db migration file. Is there something I have missed?

Comment: normally it can become messy. When i want to add a column (and it's possible of course) I will add the declatation in the migration that creates the table. If you have your data saved somewhere, simply do a rake db:reset and it will recreate the database. can you try that?

Comment: I tried that, but didn't give any result, unfortunately. I updated my post with some code. Do you see anything wrong there? Should I add some more code for you to look at?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have anything weird. I suggest to strip everything, just keep 1 or 2 attributes in every model, create the association and then add the rest of the attributes, test it again, add devise and so on.

Comment: If you do it incrementally it is much easier to find what's wrong. They way it is now, you will spend hours without being able to find the mistake. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I made a new project only with Devise (User) and a Post model (scaffold). I set up `belongs_to` and `has_many`, but even with this simple app I get `user_id: nil` in the Post table. There must be something I do wrong...

Comment: can you please write down the code of the sample project? The generator code.

Comment: Hi, I got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622087/rails-with-devise-problems-with-associations. I hadn't wrote `@post.user_id = current_user.id` in my post controller :) Thanks for your help though!