# Rails with Devise: Problems with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I have made new Rails app. It is totally fresh with just one User model (that is generated through Devise) and a Post model that is generated with scaffold. In the Post model I have a column in the database that is named `user_id`.

The problem is that `user_id` in the Post table always is `nil` (it won't change to the `user_id` of the user that is posting). I suspect that is has something to do with Devise, but I'm not totally sure. Any suggestions on what to do?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'devise'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

gem 'will_paginate', '> 3.0'
```

**post_controller (create)**

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Show your `PostController#create` method

Comment: Are you assigning anything to the user_id field? You can get the current user's id from current_user.id

Comment: Added the create method now. How should I assign it - in the create method (how)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the `user_id` attribute isn't getting set because you're not setting it. :)

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.user_id = current_user.id # You need to add this line

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Side note: I would recommend putting a not-null constraint on `post.user_id` as well as (if you haven't already) a foreign key constraint from `post.user_id` to `user.id`. Those constraints help to both prevent and more easily diagnose these kinds of problems.

Comment: I though that was taken care of "automagically" with `has_many` and `belongs_to`. But that isn't true? I need to write that line manually?

Comment: `has_many` and `belongs_to` will let you do convenient things like `user.posts` and `post.user`, but the only way to set an attribute is to either set it in the form or set it somewhere else, like the controller.

Comment: By the way, you very well could have set the post's `user_id` in the form, like with a hidden field. I tend to avoid that, though, since a savvy enough tinkerer could change the hidden field's `user_id` value to some other user's id, and then your post would get saved for the wrong user. It's not a gigantic security issue in this particular case, of course, but it's probably a good habit to practice in general.

Comment: Seriously, I have used all day on this problem. Thank you so much Jason!